# Is it possible to have two Predis connection to different databases of the same Redis instance?

Tags: php, redis, predis

I'm trying to create two Predis\Client instances on the same PHP script to separate data belonging to different logical domains.

I do this as follows:

```
$param1 = [
    'host'     => 'localhost',
    'port'     => 6379,
    'database' => 1,
];

$param2 = [
    'host'     => 'localhost',
    'port'     => 6379,
    'database' => 3,
];

[... some code ...]

$redis1 = new Predis\Client($param1);
$redis2 = new Predis\Client($param2);
```

Here is the problem:

- `$redis1` correctly stores data into database 1
- `$redis2` stores data into database 0 instead of 3

Do you have any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

Instantiate clients with `new`:

```
$redis1 = new Predis\Client([
    'host'     => 'localhost',
    'port'     => 6379,
    'database' => 1,
]);

$redis2 = new Predis\Client([
    'host'     => 'localhost',
    'port'     => 6379,
    'database' => 3,
]);
```

Comment: This was a typo, I edited the question. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer.

For some reason `$param2` was erased to `null` elsewhere in the code.

`Predis\Client` **doesn't fail** but connect with default parameters!

Comment: Yeah I set up a test here and went straight to the working outcome. Php issues errors without correct instantiation syntax, glad that you figured it out by yourself.

Comment: Thanks @Niloct. In my opinion `Predis\Client` should fail. It seems weird to me that you can find yourself writing in the wrong database.

Comment: I've only used phpredis back then because it is a compiled php extension and was faster. Have you tried it ?